# Cannot install with npm package from git

Tags: javascript, git, github, npm

I am trying to install package from git, which I forked earlier.

I try

```
npm i catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk --save-dev
```

I've got

```
npm ERR! prepareGitDep 2> npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--also=dev` instead.
```

Moreover, this error even don't depend on flag I provided. I can set --save or don't provide at all, it persists anyway. Surely, `--also=dev` doesn't change this situation

UPD: npm -v 6.14.13

UPD 2:

It appears npm for whatever reason needs sudo to run this command (I didn't use sudo with npm any times before and all other packages for app were installed without sudo). So with sudo this command runs, but only to make new error

```
    npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

For whatever reason when asking for public (!) repo it needs key

UPD 3: NodeJS (with npm) is installed through sudo dnf as Fedora module, git as usual sudo dnf install, nothing special

Comment: workaround, just put `"@tinkoff/invest-openapi-js-sdk": "github:catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk",` into dependencies

Comment: this gives me strange error (as I stated under answer)

git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Why does it want key for public repo...

Comment: `catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk` doesn't look like a local package?

Comment: See my updates. If I run npm with sudo, it actually tries to retrieve right git repo (but for whatever reason asks keys). So I do not think issue is with syntax, moreover as I understand @ is for npm registry packages and for other packages git is presumed

Answer (score 11):

> For whatever reason when asking for public (!) repo it needs key

But... An SSH URL would *always* require a public key in order to authenticate the user first, *and* then access the repository (which will be granted, since the repository is public).

If SSH is an issue:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Or even:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf ssh://
```

That way, the `npm` command will use HTTPS URLs instead of SSH ones.

Answer (score 3):

Seems it was compatibility issue. I updated npm like recommended from 6.14.13 to 7.20

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

And all issues were gone

Answer (score 1):

[Try refer this](https://techoverflow.net/2017/08/12/solving-npm-usage-of-the-dev-option-is-deprecated-use-onlydev-instead/)

```
npm install # Install only production dependencies ("dependencies", not "devDependencies")
npm install --only=dev # Install only development dependencies ("devDependencies", not "dependencies")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk --only=dev
```

Try this, the `--save-dev` option is deprecated due to changes in the future versions.

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: Try now with --only=dev

Comment: ok I understood what happens, but more is stranger. It runs with sudo rights for whatever reason (the ONLY case I needed sudo with npm), then it runs git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/catsaredoomed/invest-openapi-js-sdk.git and there fails cause cannot find Publickey. Why it wants git Publickey for public repo I dunno either

Answer (score 0):

`git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`
Please follow documentation from Github in order to add ssh access.
You have to add ssh public key on your profile.
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Verify with `ssh -vT git@github.com` and after try again to install your npm package.

Comment: Hi abewartech! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

but still error

Comment: I have the same exact issue, even though the SSH key is fine

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution works for you:
please try this

```
npm i @tinkoff/invest-openapi-js-sdk --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Issue was solved with this command  but there was some space after the hyphen .here is the command which I tried and solved the problem

```
npm i @angular/animations@latest --save
```

Make sure you need to run the command with the admin

Answer (score 0):

Wow! as @catsaredoomed suggested, this might just be a bug in specific versions of npm. In my case, it was an issue with npm **8.5.1**.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (in a docker image), and the default version of Node is `v12.22.9` with npm `v8.5.1`. Using `npm install -g npm@latest` wouldn't work for me because the absolute latest version of npm doesn't work with Node v12. I was able to determine (as of Aug 3, 2023) the latest version of npm that lists Node v12 as a supported engine is `8.19.4`. So I ran:

```bash
npm install -g npm@8.19.4
```

After I logged out of my shell and reconnected. npm is updated, and sure enough, `npm install` now works without issue.